# change src of iframe with javascript on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  have this in a javascript file to diguise the source as much as possible

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('myframe1').src = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";

});
```

and in the html

```
<iframe id="myframe1" width="900" height="700" src=""></iframe>
```

Sorry I am a bit of a notice with javascript. Any help with be great! thanks.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or plain javascript? Your code says one thing and your tagging say another.

Comment: tbh I didn't know. Glad there are both options here though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myFrame1").attr("src", "http://www.mysite.com/index.html");
    });
</script>
```

With plain javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = init;

    function init() {
        document.getElementById('myframe1').src = "http://www.mysite.com/index.html";
    }
</script>
```

You can add the function to the onload event like above.

Comment: With plain JavaScript I'd wrap the code in a function that's run when window.onload occurs, unless the script is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Did it help you or are you stuck with something?

Comment: it works when I put the (non-jquery) javascript directly in the code, but when I put it in a separate js file (eg.  <script type="javascript/text" src="blah.js"></script>) with "blah.js" containing all of the non-jquery javascript above, it doesn't.